# Error using PyVISA

Tags: python, visa

I've just installed [PyVISA](http://pyvisa.readthedocs.org/en/master/) using [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/)

```
import visa
rs = visa.ResourceManager()
```

I get this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in
>
> File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyvisa\highlevel.py", line 1486, in **new**
>
> obj.session, err = visa_library.open_default_resource_manager()
>
> File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyvisa\ctwrapper\functions.py", line 1212, in open_default_resource_manager
>
> ret = library.viOpenDefaultRM(byref(session))
>
> File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyvisa\ctwrapper\highlevel.py", line 180, in _return_handler
>
> raise errors.VisaIOError(ret_value)
>
> pyvisa.errors.VisaIOError: VI_ERROR_LIBRARY_NFOUND (-1073807202): **A code library required by VISA could not be located or loaded.**

there's a similar question posted [here](https://github.com/hgrecco/pyvisa/issues/73), based on there suggestion I've tried the following on command prompt:
`python -c "from pyvisa import util; util.get_debug_info()"` & I get this responce,

[image]

from the above picture, it's very clear that the error message is the same on both the cases, I have also checked Visa Version from NI MAX: Visa 4.3

[image]

am I missing something, Could anybody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I was able to fix the issue just by upgrading [NI VISA](http://www.ni.com/visa/) version from [4.3](http://www.ni.com/download/ni-visa-4.3/988/en/) to [5.4.1](http://www.ni.com/download/ni-visa-5.4.1/4626/en/).

- UnInstall Old NI-VISA Version from Control Panel (`National Instruments Software --> Products --> NI-VISA 4.3 & Remove`)
- Install NI-VISA 5.4.1 from [here](http://www.ni.com/download/ni-visa-5.4.1/4626/en/) and reboot your pc

not sure why Visa 4.3 produces the issue, but anyways VISA Ver. 5.4.1 is the solution in my case.